# Create a horizontal waterfall chart with python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, waterfall

I am trying to create a waterfall chart, which is like a bar chart, except that each bar starts at the end of its neighboring bars, at the end or beginning, so you have the total, and can see how it breaks down.
I am trying to create this chart in python, but there are no direct charts in `matplot.lib` called waterfall.

I found code for a vertical waterfall, but I could not transform it to horizontal.

How can I transform a `barh` matplot chart, for example, to a horizontal waterfall?

I want to create a HORIZONTAL waterfall.

For example, I am trying to make each bar in `barh` chart in matplotlib start at end of other, but I do not think I am approaching the problem the right way, because I have no results so far.
It should look like this:

[image]

Code to create the plot:

```
my_plot = trans.plot(
    kind='barh', 
    stacked=True, 
    bottom=blank,legend=None, 
    figsize=(10, 5)
)
```

How do I separate the bars?

EDIT

I have found this ready to use python package, but it doesn't work with dataframes, so I cannot use it.

```
import waterfall_chart
from matplotlib import transforms

a = ['sales','returns','credit fees','rebates','late charges','shipping']
b = [10,-30,-7.5,-25,95,-7]

my_plot = waterfall_chart.plot(a, b, rotation_value=30, sorted_value=True, threshold=0.2,
                               formatting="$ {:,.1f}", net_label="end result", other_label="misc",
                               Title="chart", x_lab="X", y_lab="money", blue_color="blue",
                               green_color="#95ff24", red_color="r")

rot = transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(90)


my_plot.show()
```

I also found this tutorial, with code, for a vertical waterfall chart.
https://pbpython.com/waterfall-chart.html.
It works great, but I didn't manage to reproduce the same thing for a horizontal waterfall.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. The way to get your question answer if by providing a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Could you edit your question accordingly?

Comment: @the-one-who-voted-to-close. It would be nice (and more productive) to help new users with helpful comments rather than simply vote the closing of their post.

Comment: I don't know about matplotlib, but I did the same chart in 4 minutes with Image-Charts static chart api https://editor.image-charts.com/#https:/image-charts.com/chart?chco=FFFFFF,7EAB54|B1D094|7EAB54|B1D094|B1D094|B1D094&chd=a:0,67,0,40,2,0|100,33,67,25,38,3&chl=||||||100%|33%|67%|27%|38%|3%&chma=0,50,50&chs=711x313&cht=bhs&chxl=0:|Total|Not%20active|Active|Only%20paid%20jobs|Paid%20and%20non%20paid%20jobs|Only%20non%20paid%20jobs&chxt=y&icac=fgribreau&icretina=1&ichm=f90cd300062725bb823e87efdcb65f19b64597bc3341dc52e145cb47ca0e9f43 :)

Comment: Thank you Alec for your comment! I didn't know what code to do but I don't know much about Python matplot lib I just know how to create simple charts I am quite new

Comment: Can you also include a pic of how it currently displays, so we have something to compare it to. Then we can see what you have vs what you want, and how the two differ.

Comment: Also, can you show the code you have, which properly shows a vertical waterfall chart. I understand that that works for you, but you don't know how to do the same, but where the bars are horizontal instead of vertical. Someone may be able to spot translation from bar to horizontal, based on the translation from bar to vertical.

Comment: Please add example data that we can use. The first comment leaves a link to the Minimal Reproducible Code requirement. It is not possible for anyone to help until you can provide everything necessary for us to copy and paste into or editors to duplicate the issue, and modify to suggest a fix. This question cannot be reopened until we have that info.